# View Transition Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, view

I have this code:

```
- (void) displayView:(int)intNewView{

NSLog(@"%i", intNewView);
[currentView.view removeFromSuperview];
[currentView release];

switch (intNewView) {
    case 1:
        currentView = [[EnterView alloc] init];
        break;
    case 2:
        currentView = [[MainMenuView alloc] init];
        break;
    case 3:
        currentView = [[DetailsView alloc] init];
        break;
    case 4:
        currentView = [[PhotosView alloc] init];
        break;
    case 5:
        currentView = [[CustomUITableViewViewController alloc] init];
        break;
}

[self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
```

}

This code successfully transitions views, however its not very spectacular as you can imagine (the view simply switches with no animation).  I'm wondering if there is a simple way to add any kind of simple view transition animation here?  I can't figure out how to implement any of the example I've found online.  Any animation would suffice, just something to spice things up a bit :)

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use basic core animations:

Like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft  forView:self.view cache:YES];


[self.view addSubview:currentView.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can try different UIViewAnimationTransitions, for the "forView" you enter the view that currently is on the screen. Hope that helped.

Comment: How to remove it? :) in same style